# How to setup Konica Minolta C224e for scan to SMB share on domain server?

Tags: network-share, printer

I am trying to set up our Office printer (Konica Minolta C224e), to save scaned files to our Windows 2012 fileserver. I created domain user printer that has access to specific shares, but no luck so far.

Printer set up does not seem to accept domain name in format DOMANIN\printer.

**WORKS** with local Admin on FileServer:
[image]

**DOES NOT WORK** with local Admin on FileServer with local DOMAIN:
[image]

**DOES NOT WORK** with local Admin on FileServer with company DOMAIN.
[image]